# How best to deal with struct field that can change types

Tags: struct, rust

I'm working with a library that uses Rust types to keep track of state. As a simplified example, say you have two structs:

```
struct FirstStruct {}
struct SecondStruct {}

impl FirstStruct {
    pub fn new() -> FirstStruct {
        FirstStruct {}
    }
    pub fn second(self) -> SecondStruct {
        SecondStruct {}
    }
    // configuration methods defined in this struct
}

impl SecondStruct {
    pub fn print_something(&self) {
        println!("something");
    }
    pub fn first(self) -> FirstStruct {
        FirstStruct {}
    }
}
```

And to actually use these structs you usually follow a pattern like so, after printing you may stay in second state or go back to first state depending on how you're using the library:

```
fn main() {
    let first = FirstStruct::new();
    let second = first.second(); // consumes first
    second.print_something();
    // go back to default state
    let _first = second.first();
}
```

I want to create my own struct that handles the state changes internally and simplifies the interface. This also lets me have a single mutable reference around that I can pass to other functions and call the print method. Using it should look something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut combined = CombinedStruct::new(FirstStruct::new());
    combined.print();
}
```

I've come up with the following solution that works, at least in this simplified example:

```
enum StructState {
    First(FirstStruct),
    Second(SecondStruct),
}

struct CombinedStruct {
    state: Option<StructState>,
}

impl CombinedStruct {
    pub fn new(first: FirstStruct) -> CombinedStruct {
        CombinedStruct {
            state: Some(StructState::First(first)),
        }
    }
    pub fn print(&mut self) {
        let s = match self.state.take() {
            Some(s) => match s {
                StructState::First(first) => first.second(),
                StructState::Second(second) => second,
            },
            None => panic!(),
        };
        s.print_something();
        // If I forget to do this, then I lose access to my struct
        // and next call will panic
        self.state = Some(StructState::First(s.first()));
    }
}
```

I'm still pretty new to Rust but this doesn't look right to me. I'm not sure if there's a concept I'm missing that could simplify this or if this solution could lead to ownership problems as my application gets more complicated. Is there a better way to do this?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=091669df8ba2ae9349a05fea58f5c13e)

Comment: why take `self` and not `&selt` or `&mut self`, why not implement `Copy` ?

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem and went basically with your solution, but I avoided the `Option`.

I.e. I basically kept your

```
enum StructState {
    First(FirstStruct),
    Second(SecondStruct),
}
```

If an operation tries to convert a `FirstStruct` to a `SecondStruct`, I introduced a function `try_to_second` roughly as follows:

```
impl StructState {
    fn try_to_second(self) -> Result<SecondState, StructState> {
        /// implementation
    }
}
```

In this case, an `Err` indicates that the `StructState` has not been converted to `SecondStruct` and preserves the status quo, while an `Ok` value indicates successfull conversion.

As an alternative, you could try to define `try_to_second` on `FirstStruct`:

```
impl FirstStruct {
    fn try_to_second(self) -> Result<FirstStruct, SecondStruct> {
        /// implementation
    }
}
```

Again, `Err`/`Ok` denote failure/success, but in this case, you have more concrete information encoded in the type.

Comment: Should the return type not be `Result<SecondState, StructState>` and `Result<SecondStruct, FirstStruct>`, respectively? Returning a `SecondStruct` on success and the original struct on failure?